# Why am I always getting output as 1 when printing a function?

Tags: c++

I am wondering why I'm always getting output as 1 when I print this function. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x(int());
    cout << x; // 1
}
```

It always prints out one. Why? I was expecting it to output 0 as ints are defaulted to 0. So why 1?

Comment: You do know that `x` is not an `int`, right? You seem to, but its not entirely clear from your question...

Comment: @K-ballo i know that. It's a function right?

Comment: Then why would you expect it to print `0`? What does _value initialization_ of `int`s have to do with that?

Comment: @K-ballo I was thinking maybe int functions are 0 by default

Comment: They don't, but even if they did your function is not even evaluated. Function evaluation takes a `()` and there is no `x()`.

Comment: In fact, your code should not even link... There is no _definition_ for that function _declaration_.

Comment: @David You're not even calling the function though (`x()`). You've just declared a function called `x` that returns an int and take a single argument.

Comment: @K-ballo It calls the `<<(bool)` overload. Conversion to bool of a function pointer is statically known to yield true. So the compiler optimizes out the reference to the function and replaces it by `true` directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int x(int());
```

is a case of "[most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)"; you think it's a declaration of an `int` (`int x`) initialized to the default value for ints (`int()`); instead, the compiler interpret it as a declaration of a function returning an `int` which takes as a parameter a (pointer to) function that takes no parameters and returns an `int` (you can get hairy declarations explained by [this site](http://cdecl.org/), or gain some more understanding about C type declarations [here](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html)).

Then, when you do:

```
cout << x;
```

`x` here decays to function pointer, but there's no overload of `operator<<` that takes a function pointer; the simplest implicit conversion that gives some valid overload of `operator<<` is to `bool`, and, since a function pointer cannot have a 0 (`NULL`) value, it is evaluated to `true`, which is printed as 1.

Notice that I'm not entirely sure that such a code should be compiled without errors - you are taking the address of a function that is only declared and not defined; it *is* true that it cannot be evaluated to anything other than `true`, but in line of principle you should get a linker error (here masked by the optimizer, that removes any reference to `x`, since it isn't actually used).

---

What you actually wanted is:

```
int x=int();
```

Answer (score 2):

The function is being converted to `bool` and is being printed as a `bool` value. The function is at a non-zero address, and so the conversion produces `true`.

This is a standard conversion sequence consisting of a function-to-pointer conversion followed by a boolean conversion.

The sequence is followed because there is no better overloaded `operator<<`.

Comment: Why would that happen? `int()` returns 0 (just tested), which would be casted to `false` anyway.

Comment: @slugonamission: `int x(int());` declares `x` as a function (returning `int` and taking an `int(*)()` argument). In this situation, `x` is not an int, and `int()` is not an `int` temporary.